# Show password field for display only

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created MVC5 app and I use the following code in create mode when user type passowrd(show asterisks ) and Its working fine .In display mode I want to display just the **asterisks** (not empty text box) for the field which the user type password ,how should I do that?

this is the code in the create

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.Password("password", "", new { id = "password", Textmode = "Password" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `placeholder` attribute:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.Password("password", "", new { id = "password", placeholder = "***", Textmode = "Password" })

        //or for displaying, just type
        <label>*****</label>

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI Jhoon- thanks but In display mode I dont want to see the text box just to see label with **** when user type it on create ,how should I do that ?

Comment: Does not "@Html.Password" do this?

Comment: You have a text box which is empty and in your suggestion 3 asterisks ,I just want it to be without text box like a label and with asterisks according to the user input,is it possible?

Comment: if I understood you right, you can write just label with ** symbols, or can add disabled = "disabled", or @readonly = "readonly" to your password tag.

Comment: Can user add password or not in your case?

Comment: The post you added is similar to what I've used in create mode when you click on create it open for you empty textBox and you type and you  see the asterisks ,when you click on create/submit you see the table ,than I want it to be like label that you will see just the asterisks without option to change and witout text box ,to be like label with the number of the asterisks of the passowrd is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use just <label>***</label>? it is your "like label"

Comment: Ok so how should I put asterisks from the model (acoording to the numbers of the charcters that was put in the passowrd ) password to that label can you please provide example (im new to this)

Comment: You want to hide user's password. yes? So, just type "****". Don't take any value from real password. If you want to know count of "*" symbols (if password count is 5, to show 5 "*" symbol. It is not right) So, you can show static "*****" symbols. You don't need to use @Model.Password value.

Comment: Thanks Jhoon I will close this question ,I'll open in 2 min new please see if you can help.Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, happy coding to you. When I am online, can try to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.Password("password", "", new { id = "password", Textmode = "Password",value="something" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

PasswordFor works real well.

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.xxxPublicAPI, new { @class = "form-control", value = Model.xxxPublicAPI })
```

The @class is for style, but the **value = Model.xxxPublicAPI** is critical.